# Mysql Select for update lock maximum duration

Tags: mysql, locking

Is there a maximum time set for how long we can hold this lock?

Or is it forever until current transaction dies or commits?

Answer (score 0):

The `innodb_lock_wait_timeout` variable defines how long locks will wait before timing out if you're using InnoDB.

The `table_lock_wait_timeout` setting is documented as "not used".

Comment: I think.. It is waiting time for new request to have lock if resource is already locked.

Comment: Please tell me...! What if resource is not released after lock?  By Neither by commit or rollback.

Comment: If they're just plain locked, then queries against that will time-out perpetually.